# Fiware ORION v2 GET operations and v1 Context Providers coexistence

Tags: fiware-orion

We are using v2 GET operations to retrieve info. If we register any context provider using v1 standard(or convenience one if neccessary) operation, will that context provider work under any v2 operation like GET v2/entities? In afirmative case, what is the expected forwarding behaviour?

Is there any working example anywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context providers (registered using NGSIv1 API) work with NGSIv2 update/query operations. However, there are some limitations [properly described in the Orion documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/v1_v2_coexistence/index.html#ngsiv2-query-update-forwarding-to-context-providers) that you should take into account.